# Traefik + Nextcloud results in bad gateway

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik, nextcloud

I have 3 services up and running.
A mariadb & nextcloud instance:

```
version: '2.1'

volumes:
  nextcloud:
  db:

services:
  db:
    image: mariadb
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my_root_password
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=my_password
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=my_database
      - MYSQL_USER=my_user
  app:
    image: nextcloud
    restart: always
    networks:
      - web
      - default
    ports:
      - 9000
    labels:
      - "traefik.backend=app"
      - "traefik.docker.network=web"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:my_host"
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.port=9000"
      - "traefik.default.protocol=http"

networks:
  web:
    external: true
```

And a traefik service:

```
version: '2'

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:1.5.4
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    networks:
      - web
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /opt/traefik/traefik.toml:/traefik.toml
      - /opt/traefik/acme.json:/acme.json
    container_name: traefik

networks:
  web:
    external: true
```

This traefik instance is using this config file:

```
debug = false

logLevel = "ERROR"
defaultEntryPoints = ["https","http"]

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
    entryPoint = "https"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
  [entryPoints.https.tls]

[retry]

[docker]
endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
domain = "my_host"
watch = true
exposedByDefault = false

[acme]
email = "my_email"
storage = "acme.json"
entryPoint = "https"
onHostRule = true
[acme.httpChallenge]
entryPoint = "http"
```

Now when I goto my host, it redirects to HTTPS but then it just displays `bad gateway` and nothing else. It should display the nextcloud web application. Anyone know why this is happening? I am running the compose files using the `docker-compose up -d` command.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be too late now but I also ran into this issue myself, so posting an answer to what resolved it for me. 

Nextcloud exposes port 80 on the container's IP address which Traefik is trying to connect to. So you incorrectly specified the port for 'traefik.port' label. Change it from 9000 to 80.